# Modify embedded Excel workbook in Word document via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a Word document with two embedded Excel files (added using Insert -> Object -> Create From File) which I wish to modify using Word VBA. I have got to the point where I am able to open the embedded files for editing (see code below), but am unable to get a handle on the Excel workbook using which I can make the modifications and save the embedded file. Does anyone have a solution for this? Thanks in advance.

```
Sub TestMacro()

    Dim lNumShapes As Long
    Dim lShapeCnt As Long
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim wrdActDoc As Document

    Set wrdActDoc = ActiveDocument

    For lShapeCnt = 1 To 1 'wrdActDoc.InlineShapes.Count
        If wrdActDoc.InlineShapes(lShapeCnt).Type = wdInlineShapeEmbeddedOLEObject Then
            If wrdActDoc.InlineShapes(lShapeCnt).OLEFormat.ProgID = "Excel.Sheet.8" Then
                'This opens the embedded Excel workbook using Excel
                wrdActDoc.InlineShapes(lShapeCnt).OLEFormat.Edit
            End If
        End If
    Next lShapeCnt

End Sub
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yikes, don't do what you're suggesting in your comment. You'll probably end up with multiple instances of Excel (check Task Manager and see how many there are after executing your code).

Firstly, add a reference to the Excel object library (Project->References & choose Microsoft Excel  Object Library). Now you can declare your objects as bona-fide Excel types and use early binding rather than declaring them as "Object" and using late binding. This isn't strictly necessary, but apart from anything else it means you get Intellisense when editing your code.

You're doing the right thing right up until you do .OleFormat.Edit. (I would personally use .OleFormat.Activate but since I've never tried using .Edit I couldn't say that it makes a difference).

Having done .Activate (or, presumably, .Edit), you can then access the OleFormat.Object member. Since the embedded Object is an Excel chart, the "Object" will be the Excel Workbook, so you can do this:

```
Dim oOleFormat as OleFormat
Set oOleFormat = ...

oOleFormat.Activate

Dim oWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Set oWorkbook = oOleFormat.Object

' Do stuff with the workbook
oWorkbook.Charts(1).ChartArea.Font.Bold = True
```

Note that you do NOT need to close Excel, and indeed you cannot - Word "owns" the instance used for an edit-in-place, and will decide when to close it. This is actually something of a problem, since there's no obvious way to force the embedded object to be de-activated, so the chart would stay open after you execute the code above.

There is a hack-y way to get the chart to close, though. If you add tell Word to activate it as something else, it'll de-activate it first. So, if you tell it to activate it as something non-sensical, you'll achieve the right result because it'll de-activate it and then fail to re-activate it. So, add the following line:

```
oOleFormat.ActivateAs "This.Class.Does.Not.Exist"
```

Note that this will raise an error, so you'll need to temporarily disable error handling using On Error Resume Next. For that reason, I normally create a Deactivate method, to avoid disrupting the error handling in my main method. As in:

```
Private Sub DeactivateOleObject(ByRef oOleFormat as OleFormat)
    On Error Resume Next
    oOleFormat.ActivateAs "This.Class.Does.Not.Exist"
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.
Gary

Comment: set oleFormat = x.inlineshapes(y).OLEFormat gives a type mismatch for me :/

Comment: Never mind, I had to specifiy the OLEFormat as a WORD.OLEFormat, I guess it was defaulting to EXCEL.OLEFormat

Comment: Don't know if it was the case in the version of Office used when this Answer was posted - this all works here in 365/2019 on Windows. The one difficulty I encounter is that the VB Editor stops single-stepping after you reach a certain point, and just runs the rest of the code. Which is a bit worrying. But it does still seem to honor breakpoints.

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution to my own problem. Any further comments will be appreciated -

```
Sub TestMacro()

    Dim lNumShapes As Long
    Dim lShapeCnt As Long
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim wrdActDoc As Document

    Set wrdActDoc = ActiveDocument

    For lShapeCnt = 1 To 1 'wrdActDoc.InlineShapes.Count
        If wrdActDoc.InlineShapes(lShapeCnt).Type = wdInlineShapeEmbeddedOLEObject Then
            If wrdActDoc.InlineShapes(lShapeCnt).OLEFormat.ProgID = "Excel.Sheet.8" Then
                wrdActDoc.InlineShapes(lShapeCnt).OLEFormat.Edit
                Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
                xlApp.Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1).Range("A1") = "This is A modified"
                xlApp.Workbooks(1).Save
                xlApp.Workbooks(1).Close
                xlApp.Quit
            End If
        End If
    Next lShapeCnt

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Have another hackey way to get the chart to close:  Simply use the find function to find something in the document that is not there.

EG

```
With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = "wiffleball"
    .Execute Forward:=True
End With
```

This will take you out of the embedded file, close the instance and back to the main document, you can just code from there.

Hope this helps, this problem was driving me crazy.

Comment: This worked for me where the other didn't(Office 2016), but with one caveat, If you just added the OLE object you need to close and quit it before you focus on another element, otherwise Excel will crash, at least on my machine. I have no idea why, but hopefully this is useful to someone else...

Answer (score 0):

When you grad the xlApp, you don't grab a specific workbook. So if you refer to a number, you may not be on the embeded file. Better use Activeworkbook.
For me workbook(1) turns out to be my personnal hidden xl file containing my personnal macros.

I don't do the tests as I only have one shape in my .docx but I think the number "Excel.Sheet.8" is rather .12 for me.

```
    Sub TestMacro()
    
        Dim lNumShapes As Long
        Dim lShapeCnt As Long
        Dim xlApp As Object
        Dim wrdActDoc As Document
        
        Set wrdActDoc = ActiveDocument
        
        For lShapeCnt = 1 To 1 'wrdActDoc.InlineShapes.Count
            If wrdActDoc.InlineShapes(lShapeCnt).Type = wdInlineShapeEmbeddedOLEObject Then
                If wrdActDoc.InlineShapes(lShapeCnt).OLEFormat.ProgID = "Excel.Sheet.8" Then
                    wrdActDoc.InlineShapes(lShapeCnt).OLEFormat.Edit
                    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
                    xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1") = "This is A modified"
                    'xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Save
                    'xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close
                    xlApp.Quit
                End If
            End If
        Next lShapeCnt
    
    End Sub
```

When I quit xlApp, the focus gets out of the embeded xl. No problem with that.